# Calculate LocalDateTime from Duration

Tags: java, datetime, intervals, duration

I have this configured Duration from fixed number of seconds:

```
Duration gap = Duration.ofSeconds(12000);
```

I want to make a SQL query with `LocalDateTime` param which is calculated from this `Duration`. I want to calculate the duration this way: The end date should be `now` - the current date. The start date should be before `12000` seconds.

Do you know how this can be implemented?

Comment: This is unclear, you talk about : now, current date, start date, end date, duration, .. Give a precise example

Comment: Do you want to retrieve datetimes that are *within* the gap? Of *outside* the gap? Or are there two datetimes in your database schema, so one should be before the gap and one after??

Answer (score 3):

> The start date should be before 12000 seconds.

You can use [`LocalDateTime::minus`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#minus-java.time.temporal.TemporalAmount-) like so :

```
Duration gap = Duration.ofSeconds(12000);
LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now().minus(gap);
```